# python ctypes OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x008B1000

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Administrator/Source/Repos/RSPluginKey/Debug/load.py", line 9, in <module>
    work.re("")#http been del
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x008B1000
```

python code

```
from ctypes import *
import os

sdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
work = CDLL(sdir + "\\RSPluginKey.dll")

print(work)

work.re("http://127.0.0.1")
```

cpp code

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "requests.h"

extern "C" {//以此格式来添加引用函数
    __declspec(dllexport) void re(std::string http);
}

void re(std::string http) {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace requests;
    Response resp = Get(http);
    cout << resp.status << endl;
    cout << resp.GetText() << endl;
}
```

the requests :https://github.com/lxwAsm/requests

maybe it's requests or else thing,i am new uesr for ctypes,need help!

how to do?please

Comment: Doesn't  make much sense to have an `extern "C"` function with an `std::string` parameter. change its signature to `char*`( and if necessary, use `Response resp = Get(std::string(http));`).

Comment: very thank!i will try more